# pygame: Random direction of a ball at the start of the game

Tags: python, algorithm, random, pygame

I'm doing the Pong game. However instead of 2 players, I'm doing it for 4 (one on each side of the screen). I need to have the ball randomly "choose" the direction it has to go.

```
import pygame
import random

class Ball(object):
    @classmethod
    def init(cls, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT):
        cls.radius = 20
        cls.centerx = SCREEN_WIDTH*0.5
        cls.centery = SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.5

        cls.rect = pygame.Rect(cls.centerx - cls.radius,
                               cls.centery - cls.radius,
                               cls.radius * 2,
                               cls.radius * 2)

    # x , y
    cls.direction = [random.choice([1, -1]), random.choice([1, -1])] 
    cls.speed = [5, 8] # x, y

    # left, right, top, bottom
    cls.hit_edge = [False, False, False, False] 

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, player1, player2, player3, player4, SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT):
        cls.centerx += cls.direction[0] * cls.speed[0]
        cls.centery += cls.direction[1] * cls.speed[1]

        cls.rect.center = (cls.centerx, cls.centery)

        #detects if someone losses
        if cls.rect.left <= 0:
            cls.hit_edge[0] = True
        elif cls.rect.right >= SCREEN_WIDTH-1:
            cls.hit_edge[1] = True
        elif cls.rect.top <= 0:
            cls.hit_edge[2] = True
        elif cls.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT-1:
            cls.hit_edge[3] = True

        #detects collision between players & the ball
        if cls.rect.colliderect(player1.rect):
            cls.direction[0] = 1
            cls.up_speed()
        elif cls.rect.colliderect(player2.rect):
            cls.direction[0] = -1
            cls.up_speed()
        elif cls.rect.colliderect(player3.rect):
            cls.direction[1] = 1
            cls.up_speed()
        elif cls.rect.colliderect(player4.rect):
            cls.direction[1] = -1
            cls.up_speed()

    @classmethod
    def up_speed(cls):
        cls.speed[0] += random.uniform(0, 0.25)
        cls.speed[1] += random.uniform(0, 0.25)

    @classmethod
        def render(cls, SCREEN, color):
        pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, color, cls.rect.center, cls.radius, 0)
```

To take into account: I had the idea to add a "0" in every random.choice(), although if I do this only function at the beginning, then it will not be able to move in the axis where the "0" . Also I have two types of speeds in X and Y, could be solved by putting a "0.1" in random.choice () but this would make when the game starts the ball goes very slow. As you would do for the ball to start in a random direction (taking into account that the speed of the ball at the start must be the same for all players. If the ball goes at the beginning to the left,and later (in another game) when it starts but the ball goes up has to go at the same speed)

Comment: It's really odd that you use `@classmethod` everywhere. Where did you learn that? It has some special purposes like creating alternative constructors, but it shouldn't be used for every method of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a little over-complicating things, but if you know the speed you want the ball to start with overall, you could use something like this:

1. Generate random number between 0-1
2. `angle` = 360 * random number
3. `xSpeed` = `startSpeed` * sin(`angle`)
4. `ySpeed` = `startSpeed` * cos(`angle`)

This will mean that your ball will always travel at the same speed. The only thing that is random is the direction it travels in.

Comment: This is the right way. A few tips: `random.uniform(0, 360)` returns a float between 0 and 360. You need to convert the angle to radians before you pass it to sin and cos `math.sin(math.radians(angle))` or alternatively just generate an angle in radians `angle = random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)`. You need sin for the ySpeed and cos for the xSpeed, but it actually doesn't matter here. And if you switch to vectors, you don't even have to calculate the x- and y-speed anymore and can just rotate the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use vectors. For the velocity you can just pick an arbitrary start speed like (8, 0) and then rotate the vector by a random angle.

```
position = pg.math.Vector2(100, 200)
velocity = pg.math.Vector2(8, 0).rotate(random.randrange(360))
```

To update the position:

```
position += velocity
```

Here's an example program that spawns balls with random color and velocity.

```
import sys
import math
from random import randrange
import pygame as pg


class Ball(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30), pg.SRCALPHA)
        col = randrange(256), randrange(256), randrange(256)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, col, (15, 15), 15)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(8, 0).rotate(randrange(360))
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > 640:
            self.vel.x *= -1
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > 480:
            self.vel.y *= -1


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    sprite_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    ball = Ball((320, 240), sprite_group)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                sprite_group.add(Ball((320, 240)))

        sprite_group.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprite_group.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: As you see, you don't need `@classmethod` and can use `self` instead of `cls` which refers to the instance not the class.